# About the jQuery mobile <input type="range">

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I used jqm to create an input tag ,like this

`<input type="range" min="1" max="40" value="1" step="0.1" autocomplete="off"/>`

i writed javascript code

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').click(function(){
    var pix = parseFloat($(this).attr("title"));
    console.log(pix);
});
```

there is no problem on pc,but not on mobile ,so i changed my code
like this

`$('.ui-slider-handle').on("tap",function(){
        var pix = parseFloat($(this).attr("title"));
        console.log(pix);
    });`

it's still not work!

THX!

Comment: can you try doing something as `$( "#slider_id" ).on( "slidestop", function( event ) {
 console.log(event.target.value);
} )` ?

Comment: i'm sorry dude.it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-1">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h4>Slider</h4>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <label for="slider">Slider</label>
      <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" min="1" max="40" value="1" step="0.1" autocomplete="off" />
      slidestart: <input type="text" id="txt1">
      slidechange: <input type="text" id="txt2">
      slidestop: <input type="text" id="txt3">
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-1", function() {
  $("#slider").on("slidestart", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#txt1").val(val);
  });
  $("#slider").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#txt2").val(val);
  });
  $("#slider").on("slidestop", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#txt3").val(val);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/8js4npso/